# Why is WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE really an int? Shouldn‘t it be an enum?

Tags: java, enums, jcomponent

Wouldn't it be better practice for EXIT_ON_CLOSE and all of those args to be an enum instead of final variables?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a backwards compatible type issue. Window has been around since before Java 1.5 when enums were first introduced. If they were to change it to enum, it would break legacy code.

Answer (score -1):

enum is an object, int is a primitive data type. You can see that mark or signal attributes are defined with final static int in the same class. You can find kind of usage in Calendar, Character etc. But if you define attributes with enum, it probably needs another enum Class.

This kind of attributes just used for compare, no more needs. While enum can have more usages other than compare. So it's not necessary to use enum.
I believe enum would not be better solution, if enum is, a new class would be defined and WindowConstants would be marked as @Deprecated.